# Docker Compose on Cloud Init Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cloud-init

There is a VM scale set running with Centos 7 custom image. Required to run below script as cloud-init script while scaling the VM Scale set. But VM scaled, the script not executed. From the server also not able to locate the execution history. This is the command I used,

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
– cd /srv/compose/composeforsvaret/
– docker-compose stop
- docker-compose up -d
final_message: &quot;Your Docker server is now ready.&quot;
```

Comment: Where do you have this script? Is it in a pipeline, or a cronjob on your VM, or...?

Comment: @CasperDijkstra I added that script to the cloud init script box on th Azure portal. Operating System > Script box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands are not executed, because the syntax is not recognized. 
I read in the [cloud init documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html) about `runcmd`

> the list has to be proper yaml, so you have to quote any characters yaml would eat (':' can be problematic)

This should do the trick:

```
runcmd:
– [ cd, /srv/compose/composeforsvaret, / ] // or - [ sh, -c , "cd /srv/compose/composeforsvaret" ]
– [ sh, -c, "docker-compose stop" ]
- [ sh, -c, "docker-compose up -d" ]
final_message: "Your Docker server is now ready."
```

Also keep in mind that `runcmd` only runs during the first boot, so depending on your purpose you should consider `bootcmd`!